# How to set Views aggregation to group by just one field?

Tags: 7, views

I would like to achieve something like this with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

`select o.id, o.title, o.date, sum(o.price) as total from orders o group by o.id, title;`

However, when I choose to use aggregation on this display the SQL will become grouping by all the fields that I selected, like:

`select o.id, o.title, o.date, sum(o.price) as total from orders o group by  o.id, o.title, o.date;`

I don't see a "Do not use aggregation for this field" setting on Aggregation type settings form.

Can I achieve this without query_alter hooks?

## update

It turns out that my desired SQL is only valid in MySQL, and not in SQL standard, so I just cannot achieve this via Views.

Comment: As you are selecting from one table only and the first order grouping is by id (which I assume is unique), won't the result be the same? If you just want the SUM I would think you'd need to drop all the fields except the price field from Views display.

Comment: I finally figured out that the MySQL way is not reasonable to choose a random value for these fields, so I removed these non-unique fields (like o.date). Thanks!